# In Chef how do you override default attribute values in node.json

Tags: chef

I'm running chef-solo with `chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -ldebug` and it's failing because nginx cookbook/recipe refers to user "www-data" which I don't have. Can I change the value in node.json file? My node.json looks like this:

```
{
  "nginx": {
    "user": "my_username"
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[nginx]",
    "recipe[mysql::server]"
  ]
}
```

**My problem is** the Opscode nginx recipe appears to ignore this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** :-)

`www-data` is just a default user that is found on debian (and debian-like systems) for running web servers. Change it to something other than `root` and you should be fine. For most distros where there is no `www-data` there is a `httpd` user, otherwise you can `nobody`.

If you are on windows then use an appropriate user.

Comment: If that doesn't work, let me know which nginx recipe you are using -- it may be hardcoded to `www-data` in which case you may need another recipe. The [opscode nginx recipe](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/nginx) allows the 'user' to be specified as in your question.

Comment: I was using the opscode nginx recipe, but it always threw the error about www-data user being used so I don't think this worked. I actually had "root" as the user. Eventually I wrote my own recipe which installs nginx package and uses a template to overwrite nginx.conf.

Comment: The (opscode nginx recipe)[https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/blob/master/nginx/metadata.rb] shows `nginx/user` defined and `www-data` set as the default so I would assume it should be overridden with the code you posted. Strange that it isn't. Either incorrect method of defining the user or it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The "json_attribs" file passed with the `-j` option to chef-{client,solo} is intended to be representative of the "default" node object similar to what would happen if you performed a `knife node create FOO` to create a new, blank node on a Chef Server. To override the attributes in cookbooks, you should apply them with roles.

Chef Solo can use roles. You have to specify the `role_path` in the configuration file.

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Solo#ChefSolo-Roles

Comment: I think your link is now http://docs.getchef.com/chef_solo.html#roles. Is there any documentation elaborating on what can and cannot be done in a node json file because http://docs.getchef.com/knife_node.html doesn't seem to cover attributes...